# Every natural number in binary can be cut and added so that it is a power of $2$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, proof-explanation

I was watching a google  techtalk with Donald Knuth and he mentions for every binary number $\overline{a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n}$ there exists $c_1<c_2<\dots <c_r=n$ so that:

$\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_{c_1}}+\overline{a_{c_1+1}a_{c_1+2}\dots a_{c_2}}+ \dots + \overline{a_{c_{r-1}+1}a_{c_{r-1}+2}\dots a_{c_r}}$ is a power of $2$.

Or in other words: every binary number can be separated into continuous pieces, which add up to a power of $2$. I have tried proving this for a bit, but I haven't gotten anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I can't see how this holds for $21 = \overline{10101}$. No matter how I cut the binary representation up, I can't seem to make the segments sum to a power of 2.

Comment: @ajcr $10_2 + 1_2 + 01_2 = 2 + 1 + 1 = 4 = 2^2$

Comment: Ah - I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: There is a discussion [here](http://psankar.blogspot.com/2011/07/possible-mistake-in-donald-knuths-talk.html?showComment=1311157108438) with a proof by induction. I haven't walked through it yet, but it's probably worth someone creating an answer out of it.

Comment: @shoover unfortunately none of the proofs in that link are correct

Comment: Ah well. Nice question, OP!

Comment: Wait, that solution actually seems correct. Because if we can't erase zeroes then the statement is false. for example with 10001.

Comment: @dREaM could you expand on your comment? I'm not sure I see what you mean.

Comment: I am reffering to Sanket's solution in the link provided by Shoover. The reason why they say it is wrong is because his solution assumes we can cut out "zeroes" insependently (so that they don't count). But if that was in fact not possible then the problem would be false, for example: we would not be able to get a power of $2$ from $1100$. So I think Sanket's solution is good. And really elegant imho.

Comment: @dREaM you get a power of 2 from $1100$ by $2^1=1+1+0+0$. The problem with Sanket's solution is that "deleting a zero" from a string of length $n+1$ gives you two strings, one of length $k$ and the other of length $n-k$, instead of one string of length $n$ (except if the zero is at the end)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're 100% correct, thank you for catching that :)

Comment: This has been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157354/sumpartitionbinary-string-2k

Comment: @Zander: You should vote to close this one as a duplicate, then.